# How to check name servers for reverse DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I use `whois example.com` to check which are the authoritative name servers for that domain. Now I want to know which are the authoritative name servers for a block of IP addresses for their PTR records, how can I check that? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puting information into whois depends on owner of block address - it's not obligatory. If owner put it, you can ask for example as

```
whois 1.254.150.in-addr.arpa
```

If you want to ask for authoritative nameserver, better ask ns-es for it desceding for every octet, for example:

```
undefine@undefine-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ host -t NS 150.in-addr.arpa
150.in-addr.arpa name server apnic.authdns.ripe.net.
150.in-addr.arpa name server ns1.apnic.net.
150.in-addr.arpa name server tinnie.arin.net.
150.in-addr.arpa name server ns3.apnic.net.
150.in-addr.arpa name server ns4.apnic.net.
150.in-addr.arpa name server ns2.lacnic.net.
150.in-addr.arpa name server apnic1.dnsnode.net.
undefine@undefine-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ host -t NS 254.150.in-addr.arpa
254.150.in-addr.arpa name server ns.ripe.net.
254.150.in-addr.arpa name server rose.man.poznan.pl.
254.150.in-addr.arpa name server sunflower.man.poznan.pl.
undefine@undefine-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ host -t NS 1.254.150.in-addr.arpa
1.254.150.in-addr.arpa name server orion.put.poznan.pl.
1.254.150.in-addr.arpa name server sol.put.poznan.pl.
1.254.150.in-addr.arpa name server sunflower.man.poznan.pl.
```

Another option is using dnstracetool. for example:

```
undefine@undefine-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ dnstracer -4 -s A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET 140.141.180.213.in-addr.arpa
Tracing to 140.141.180.213.in-addr.arpa[a] via A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET, maximum of 3 retries
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET (198.41.0.4) 
 |\___ a.in-addr-servers.arpa [in-addr.arpa] (2001:0500:0013:0000:0000:0000:0000:0073) Not queried
 |\___ a.in-addr-servers.arpa [in-addr.arpa] (199.212.0.73) 
 |     |\___ tinnie.arin.net [213.in-addr.arpa] (199.212.0.53) 
 |     |     |\___ dns3.onet.pl [141.180.213.in-addr.arpa] (213.180.147.200) 
 |     |     |\___ dns1.onet.pl [141.180.213.in-addr.arpa] (213.180.128.242) 
 |     |      \___ dns2.onet.pl [141.180.213.in-addr.arpa] (213.180.137.160) 
 |     |\___ tinnie.arin.net [213.in-addr.arpa] (2001:0500:0013:0000:0000:0000:c7d4:0035) Not queried
 |     |\___ pri.authdns.ripe.net [213.in-addr.arpa] (193.0.9.5)
```

You can also use dig to trace dnsservers, for example:

```
undefine@undefine-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ dig +trace 141.180.213.in-addr.arpa

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> +trace 141.180.213.in-addr.arpa
;; global options: +cmd
.           116349  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           116349  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           518057  IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20160414050000 20160404040000 60615 . pRQcZjdxUQk8wXYugudP6hxIoftDZ40Ofg8jL3I12Qi4ohu5zmABUngi ecglIDv9CNfP8WmzvRV8YfojLR2jLLPuaeBHLBr6bCJEcoI3HMzZXefY 0vEQ+MGGx1I6LbQPqmfwUnaxFOTV3Sf2THqHvFoTOcGtDln/7S692q+K S/Y=
;; Received 913 bytes from 172.31.31.31#53(172.31.31.31) in 39 ms

in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  b.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  c.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  d.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  e.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  f.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN  DS  47054 8 2 5CAFCCEC201D1933B4C9F6A9C8F51E51F3B39979058AC21B8DF1B1F2 81CBC6F2
in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN  DS  53696 8 2 13E5501C56B20394DA921B51412D48B7089C5EB6957A7C58553C4D4D 424F04DF
in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN  DS  63982 8 2 AAF4FB5D213EF25AE44679032EBE3514C487D7ABD99D7F5FEC3383D0 30733C73
in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20160413180000 20160403170000 38746 arpa. VX53RKpx6w0zTPAHbWssxukkwqqEHf52SC0fCqMA05wuf7Ye1M8DdI/F fD8pZypFAcQ5I/y+c4V6o+g8M21G6kJSIk3ZPfBWpGOWyUYtmLNXRwzE cEj6Gr40LwTjNfT0oh/e3x5MEpp+oST2wA0iM2y605LZlyNFCTQ/e8mF kJA=
;; Received 737 bytes from 192.58.128.30#53(j.root-servers.net) in 21 ms

213.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  ns3.nic.fr.
213.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  pri.authdns.ripe.net.
213.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  sec1.apnic.net.
213.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  sec3.apnic.net.
213.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  sns-pb.isc.org.
213.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  tinnie.arin.net.
213.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  DS  38870 8 2 FB9D9B5A72B7A1F6B084018119354A23AAAF434A056B8BEE0A77DD12 F77750E7
213.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 3 86400 20160416101758 20160325215946 10720 in-addr.arpa. II/3Q2FWRcz08KTGrvzTgNQz/GmOHYVwy4JTooLJA3NQof6Ybnpr5KIm VJbO/iPexiKLG1Y6RhRW4pOacImMjfrYdkuSA11yaqDJ//JZkX1IUEiZ RFhSL34dPGnpRWrmJR6q2+6yzqjDAcpfZBG2XURxEpXg4D1Wl+8L3qer B30ILeY=
;; Received 432 bytes from 199.253.183.183#53(b.in-addr-servers.arpa) in 35 ms

141.180.213.in-addr.arpa. 172800 IN NS  dns2.onet.pl.
141.180.213.in-addr.arpa. 172800 IN NS  dns3.onet.pl.
141.180.213.in-addr.arpa. 172800 IN NS  dns1.onet.pl.
141.180.213.in-addr.arpa. 3600  IN  NSEC    142.180.213.in-addr.arpa. NS RRSIG NSEC
141.180.213.in-addr.arpa. 3600  IN  RRSIG   NSEC 8 5 3600 20160503170152 20160403160152 2878 213.in-addr.arpa. FpW883TIz9SxqyEarBr5hTx4wLTPwk2Ey2Ps5BQqrWtocCPHq/BDEW7u aktTAH6ik7NzcYarleElzO0GyG5XyR4DkHy+j3sHzmqWtwDta9WSwQ/f ajm9187SYo2HaPu0bQ3Y9OKvA4iSgBGxheFfkdQE4Yuor2Mm9Hjy/L4r JdA=
;; Received 339 bytes from 192.134.0.49#53(ns3.nic.fr) in 56 ms

141.180.213.in-addr.arpa. 7200  IN  SOA dns1.onet.pl. dns.onet.pl. 2015112402 300 7200 2419200 86400
;; Received 105 bytes from 213.180.128.242#53(dns1.onet.pl) in 15 ms
```

Comment: or quick and dirty and use `dig +trace 1.254.150.in-addr.arpa` to get the above in one go